# When does a family of functions determine a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Perhaps this is a vague question, but when is a continuously indexed class of continuous real alued  functions $\{f_{\nu}\}_{\nu\in \mathbb{R}}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ on $[0,\infty)$ measure determining? That is, when we have a sequence of probability measures $\mu_{n}$, if $\int f_{\nu}d\mu_{n}\to \int f_{\nu}d\mu$ then $\mu_{n}\to \mu$ weakly. Clearly this is true for $f_{\nu}(x)=e^{i\nu x}$. I suppose more specifically, is it true for $f_{\nu}(x)=\log(x^{2}+\nu^{2})$ assuming the relevant integrals are all well defined? I know about the condition using the Stone-Weirstrass theorem but for the specific family listed above that does not hold.